# Universal exception handler for string.format()

Tags: python-3.x, exception

TL;DR

I'm working on a tkinter program and I often use the .format(). I write messages on a console. The program has external translation possibilities and the translator needs to use {} with indexes. In the main language file (transltions are a separate file) there is explanation which index is what. The problem is there is the possibility of IndexError if they use a number higher than programmed. Instead of having try: except: everytime I call my so called self.queue(string) method I would like to "bind" a try except to the format method, so whenever it causes an exception in the entire program a handler is called.

Short version:

How to bind an exception handler to the .format() method or any other method if needed ?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I that your best bet is to write a wrapper function such as:

```
def tryprint(template, *args):
    try:
        print(template.format(*args)
    except IndexError as err:
        <handle IndexError, err>
```

Comment: Ah Okay I will find a solution using a wrapper thanks !